# how to Use <c:forEach> in scripts tag on JSP page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, foreach, jstl

Hey How to use  loop in  tag in jsp page?

i want to use JSTL data to pass in data tables

my code is like :

```
        $(document).ready(function() {


            /* Init DataTables */
            var startString = "[";
            var mainString = "";
            var endString = "]";


            var temp = ${k.size()};
        <c:forEach items="${k}" var="stdn" varStatus="status">
            temp--;
            if (temp === 0) {
                mainString = mainString + "{key:\"" + "${stdn.key}" + "\",name:\"" + "${stdn.value.name}" + "\",rollno:\"" + "${stdn.value.rollNo}" + "\",marks:\"" + "${stdn.value.marks}" + "\"}";
            } else {
                mainString = mainString + "{key:\"" + "${stdn.key}" + "\",name:\"" + "${stdn.value.name}" + "\",rollno:\"" + "${stdn.value.rollNo}" + "\",marks:\"" + "${stdn.value.marks}" + "\"},";
            }
        </c:forEach>
                var finalString = startString + mainString + endString;
                var final = eval(finalString);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:forEach>YOUR CODE </title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   NAME <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

This would produce following result:

```
NAME 1
NAME 2
NAME 3
NAME 4
NAME 5
```

Above is simplest example..
following is with items var

```
<table>
      <c:forEach var="student" items="${person.person}" varStatus="counter">
        <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${counter.count % 2 == 0}">
            <c:set var="rowStyle" scope="page" value="odd"/>
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="rowStyle" scope="page" value="even"/>
          </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        <tr class="ÃÂ${rowStyle}">
          <td>${student.name}</td>
          <td>${student.age}</td>
          <td>${student.height}</td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

this way you can use the  `<c:forEach>  </c:forEach>` TAG..

If you have any specific problem then please explain

Comment: It is working fine but problem is it showing me error mark in netBeans.

Comment: i used <c:forEach> tag within that <script> tag thats why it is showing me an error if i use directly in 
<table> tag its not showing me any error..

Comment: so if your aim acchieved by putting it in table then whats the problem?its may be netbeans editor problem

Comment: some time its showing error in editor..but thats actually limited to editor...not a really error..was facing that issues in eclipse editor with some js file