# Send list object as parameter to jsp side

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to send a list as parameter to a JSP file where i want it showed. 
My JSP file is called showList.jsp.

Have created a servlet which i use to control everything in my program. When a user click on a button "show List" some code will be performed, and this code will print out the list:

**my code:**

```
if (session.getAttribute("show") == "show") {

        List opr = null;
        try {

            opr  = func.showlist(opr);
            for(int i = 0; i < opr.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(opr.get(i));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.print("Error found, when trying to show list");

        }

        session.removeAttribute("administrator");
        session.removeAttribute("show");
        session.removeAttribute("create");
        return;

    }
```

Here you can see it just prints what's in my arraylist (size).

**Updated code:**

```
  List opr = null;
        try {

            opr  = func.showlist(opr);
            for(int i = 0; i < opr.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(opr.get(i));

            }
            request.setAttribute("list", opr);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.print("Error found, when trying to show list");

        }

        session.removeAttribute("administrator");
        session.removeAttribute("show");
        getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/getList.jsp");

    }
```

Comment: `== "show"` does't look good. You should use `equals` method to check if state of two object is the same.

Comment: oki.. i changed that thx so far :)

Comment: I want to send my list to an jsp, so i can print it out in another file called showList.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Try with **JSP JSTL** to iterate a list in JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
...

<c:if test="${not empty list}">
    <table>
        <c:forEach var="x" varStatus="status" items="${list}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${x}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

Simply set the data as request attribute using [ServletRequest#setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

For more samples have a look at below posts:

- [how to Use  in scripts tag on JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502977/how-to-use-cforeach-in-scripts-tag-on-jsp-page)
- [How to access a request attribute set by a servlet in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898393/how-to-access-a-request-attribute-set-by-a-servlet-in-jsp)