# Looping on a list of objects in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a simple spring mvc application which populates a dropdown box based on another. I am sending my pojo class to jsp page - 'info' . which contains list of objects .

I want to populate the 2nd list bases on the first list with the data of the list .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>HELLO WORLD</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


      $("#selectApi").change(function(){
       var x =$("#selectApi").val();
       var privateMeth = '${apiInfo.getPrivateApiMethods()}';
       var publicMeth = '${apiInfo.getPublicApiMethods()}';
       if(x=="privateApi"){
            $("#selectFunction").append(new Option('${apiInfo.getPrivateApiMethods().get(0).getMethodName()}', "val"))
        }

        **for(i in '${publicMeth}){
            alert(i)

        }**
        alert("end")

      });
    });




</script>

 First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value=${privateMethods}><br>
<select id ="selectApi">
<option>----select an api------</option>
<option value="privateApi">PrivateAPI</option>
<option value="publicApi">PublicAPI</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="selectFunction">
<option>----select a function------</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

How can i do for loop on privateMeth ?

here is my pojo classes

```
public class ApiInfo {

    List<PrivateApiMethod> privateApiMethods;

    List<PublicApiMethod> publicApiMethods;

    public List<PrivateApiMethod> getPrivateApiMethods() {
        return privateApiMethods;
    }

    public void setPrivateApiMethods(List<PrivateApiMethod> privateApiMethods) {
        this.privateApiMethods = privateApiMethods;
    }

    public List<PublicApiMethod> getPublicApiMethods() {
        return publicApiMethods;
    }

    public void setPublicApiMethods(List<PublicApiMethod> publicApiMethods) {
        this.publicApiMethods = publicApiMethods;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
    }
}


------------------------

public class PrivateApiMethod {

    String methodName;
    String methodType;
    String numOfParam;

    public String getMethodName() {
        return methodName;
    }

    public void setMethodName(String methodName) {
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

    public String getMethodType() {
        return methodType;
    }

    public void setMethodType(String methodType) {
        this.methodType = methodType;
    }

    public String getNumOfParam() {
        return numOfParam;
    }

    public void setNumOfParam(String numOfParam) {
        this.numOfParam = numOfParam;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this,
                ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
    }
}
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand completely what you are trying to achieve.

If you just need to populate the list with the return value from a getter Method, then you could use something like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<jsp:useBean id="apiinfo" class="your.package.ApiInfo" />
<c:forEach var="method" items="${apiinfo.privateApiMethods}">
  <option>${method.methodName}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

for further reference:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm (Access Java Beans from JSP)

[how to Use <c:forEach> in scripts tag on JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502977/how-to-use-cforeach-in-scripts-tag-on-jsp-page) (Use of foreach in JSP)

Comment: Hi @mish can we use scriptlets in jquery.?

Comment: I don't think so (but not sure). http://codingforums.com/javascript-programming/172082-jsp-scriptlet-javascript.html

Comment: What I need is if option 1 in first list is selected, then I need to add the private methods to the second select,  if we choose option 2 of the first select then add public methods to the list.

Comment: I would recommend wrapping your POJO in a servlet and fetching the data via jquerys ajax function.