# Multiple annotations found at this line: in jsp code

Tags: java, jsp

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
        <title> :: Employee List :: </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border=1>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th colspan=2>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> <!-- My warnings start from here for unknown tag... -->

            <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${employee.employeeId}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${employee.employeeName}" /></td>

                    <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" value="${employee.dob}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${employee.salary}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${employee.active}" /></td>
                    <td><a href="EmployeeServlet?action=edit&empId=<c:out value="${employee.employeeId}"/>">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a href="EmployeeServlet?action=delete&empId=<c:out value="${employee.employeeId}"/>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><a href="EmployeeServlet?action=insert">Add Employee</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
 <tr>
 <td><c:out value="${employee.employeeId}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${employee.employeeName}" /></td>
 
 <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd" value="${employee.dob}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${employee.salary}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${employee.active}" /></td>
 <td><a href="EmployeeServlet?action=edit&empId=<c:out value="${employee.employeeId}"/>">Update</a></td>
 <td><a href="EmployeeServlet?action=delete&empId=<c:out value="${employee.employeeId}"/>">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>

Comment: for each doesnt respond getting warning

Comment: You should [include the taglib for the JSTL core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502977/how-to-use-cforeach-in-scripts-tag-on-jsp-page#answer-18503132).

Comment: do you have Servlet-api.jar in your classpath?

Comment: @kalaiarasan i have sir

Comment: Please read a tutorial e.g [*JSTL foreach tag example in JSP - looping ArrayList*](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/jstl-foreach-tag-example-in-jsp-looping.html).

Comment: prev error gone... but now it tells"The tag handler class for "c:out" (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag) was 
 not found on the Java Build Path"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you include all the required jars in your build path, and most important you are missing the import of JSTL core taglib in your JSP document, add the following:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

For further information take a look at this tutorial:

- **[How do I use JSTL on my JSPs?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-jstl-on-my-jsps.html)**

Comment: thank u sir now it works but in date it tell "Formats a date and/or time using the supplied styles and pattern" ""value" does not support runtime expressions"

Comment: did you include this: `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the  core tag lib in your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same and forgot to include jstl core taglib.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Also use `isELIgnored="false"` in page tag.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false" %>
```